# Bounding box coordinate measuring in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new for matlab. I want to measure the x and y coordinates and centroid of the bounding box in an RGB or grayscale image. I don't know what I should do to solve this. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

This is the code that I have so far

```
frame=step(obj);
bbox=step(faceDetector,frame);
boxInserter  = insertObjectAnnotation(frame,'rectangle',bbox, 'Face Detected');
imshow(boxInserter,'border','tight');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of faces your frame has, the `step` method returns a `bbox` matrix with different dimensions, which contains the coordinates of the bounding box itself. See here for a description of `bbox`:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetector.step.html

So, for example,

```
% Create a cascade detector object.
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();

% Read a video frame and run the detector.
videoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader('visionface.avi');
videoFrame      = step(videoFileReader);
bbox            = step(faceDetector, videoFrame);
```

returns this in `bbox`:

```
264   122    93    93
```

The format of these numbers is:  [x y width height]

and so the x, y location of the face is [264, 122]. Computing the centroid from these numbers should be fairly straightforward then.